# $G$ abelian group, $H\leq G$ such that $G/H\simeq\{0\}$. Then $H=G$?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, abelian-groups

I'm struggling with this simple fact about chain complexes:

"A complex $\mathcal{C}$ is exact in $C_q$ if and only if $H_q(\mathcal{C})\simeq\{0\}$"

It is clear to me that if it's exact in $C_q$ then $Ker\partial_q=Im\partial_{q+1}$ so the quotient $H_q(\mathcal{C})$ is trivial. But I can't really prove the opposite implication. I guess it would follow if this lemma were true

"Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H\leq G$ such that $G/H\simeq\{0\}$. Then $H=G$"

This lemma is true if $G$ is finite by Lagranges's Theorem, as $[G:H]=1$, but is it true for any abelian group?

Thanks is advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true for every group $G$.

Suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/H$ contains only one element.

In other words, there is only one left coset of $H$ in $G$, and it must be equal to $H$.

Because $G$ is the union of left cosets of $H$, conclude that $G = H$.

Comment: No need to take $H$ normal.

Comment: That's right. For every subgroup $H$, if there is only one coset for $H$ in $G$, then $G = H$.